# How to remove unhandled path URL from ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Disclaimer: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate, because there's no way no one asked this, but I don't know if i searched the wrong terms or so but I couldn't find an answer, so I'll ask here.

I'm using React routers (`react-router-dom`), so for example if I set:

```
<Route path='/home' component={Home} />
```

At this point, obviously, if I go to `localhost:3000/home` it will load my homepage, right?
But if I go to `localhost:3000/fjnisodjuhfosij` (just random text) it will load anyway a blank page, it won't say something like "this page doesn't exist" or just redirecting to the home.
How can I handle this? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just add `Route` with path '*':

```
<Route path='*' component={YourComponent} />
```

Answer (score 1):

To direct to home: Add this as the last route in switch: `<Route><Redirect to="/home"/></Route>`

Or, to show a 404 error page: Create a component for the error page (`NotFound` lets say) and add it as the last route: `<Route component={NotFound} />`

Comment: this works fine, but now i got a new problem, I set a route on `/`  that redirects to `home` and a route that redirects to `not found`, but now every unknow route, just get redirected to home.

Comment: Could you share the whole `<Router>` part? You should use`exact` for the route `/`.